# implementation of if command in variables

Tags: javascript, variables, inline-if

here is my code:

```
var a=false;
var b=false;
var c=true;
var d=false;
//
var x = a ? a : (b ? b : (c ? c: false)) ;
//
for(i=0;i<11;i++){
    document.write(x);
}
```

the inline if command check's which variable (a,b,c) is **true** then equal's **x** to that
and in the loop it will write that 10 times
there are two assumptions:

- **first**: it will execute if command 10 times in loop to get final value of **x**
- **second**: it will execute if command just one time just into **x** at first and in loop **x** will be just a variable containing **true**

  which one is true?

  thanks

Comment: exception run is not defined, question is hard to understand, what are you asking ? should "run" be "x" ?

Comment: JavaScript does not have lazy evaluation. Everything is evaluated immediately. Hope that helps.

Comment: this is just a sample code .

Comment: This is a syntax error, the last conditional operator is missing its else part.

Comment: Why not just `var x = a || b || c`?

Comment: this is able too , but i'm asking for something like @Felix said

Comment: Why not run the damn code and figure it out? For example, in the `for` loop, try setting `c = false`. Does `x` change? There's your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it contains a typo anyway, to be sure it should rather look like :

```
var x = a ? a : (b ? b : (c ? c: false)) ;
```

so you could test it like:

```
var a=false;
var b=false;
var c=false;
var d=false;

var x = a ? a : (b ? b : (c ? c: "everything false")) ;


function runTest(){
    for(i=0;i<11;i++){
        console.log(x);
    }   
}
```

so when you runTest() is will log  "everything false"
changing the variable b=true in console, e.g without refreshing the page, so your scenario and runTest() again it will still prin "everything false"

so the answer is

once x is assigned the expression, x IS the *result* of the expression and not the expression itself, and when you print x some later it still is the same result, even if the result of the expression now would be different ( because some gobal variables changed )

to let x always be "up to date" make it a function

```
x = function () {
  return a ? a : (b ? b : (c ? c: false)) ;
}
```

then it would evaluate on every call